# timediff between rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, time

I have to following query below  **fig.1** , which works, but what I would like to do is get the timediff between row 4 and row 5 then get the difference between row 5 and row 6.

The aim would be to get something like **fig.2** Ideally I'd like to do this with in a query and not have to cycle through each row within the database then return to PHP.

Thanks in advance.

---

**fig.1**

```
select * from ModuleFlowModuleStatus where ModuleCode = "LW2205" ORDER BY UpdatedOn;


| ID  | Module | MoudleStatus            | UpdatedOn           |

|   4 | LW2205 | Draft exam received     | 2017-10-18 12:41:12 |

|   5 | LW2205 | Draft exam received     | 2017-10-18 12:41:23 |

|   7 | LW2205 | Draft exam received     | 2017-10-20 15:06:46 |

| 275 | LW2205 | Exam approved by Dean   | 2017-11-14 16:39:28 |

| 288 | LW2205 | Final exam sign off by  | 2017-11-21 12:28:59 |

| 295 | LW2205 | Exam sent to SREO (Stud | 2017-11-23 09:53:30 |

+-----+--------+-------------------------+---------------------+
```

---

**fig.** 2 Expected result

```
| ID  | Module | MoudleStatus            | UpdatedOn           | Diff(days)

|   4 | LW2205 | Draft exam received     | 2017-10-18 12:41:12 | 0

|   5 | LW2205 | Draft exam received     | 2017-10-18 12:41:23 | 0

|   7 | LW2205 | Draft exam received     | 2017-10-20 15:06:46 | 2

| 275 | LW2205 | Exam approved by Dean   | 2017-11-14 16:39:28 | 24

| 288 | LW2205 | Final exam sign off by  | 2017-11-21 12:28:59 | 7

| 295 | LW2205 | Exam sent to SREO (Stud | 2017-11-23 09:53:30 | 3

+-----+--------+-------------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Which version of mysql are you on?

Comment: I'm on version  5.1.73

Answer (score 1):

This SQL code should work for you applied to the table in Fig.1:

```
SELECT
  t1.ID,
  t1.Module,
  t1.MoudleStatus,
  t1.UpdatedOn,
  IFNULL(DATEDIFF(
    t1.UpdatedOn,
    (SELECT MAX(t2.UpdatedOn) FROM ModuleFlowModuleStatus AS t2 WHERE t2.id < t1.id)
  ), 0) AS `Diff(Days)`
FROM
  ModuleFlowModuleStatus AS t1;
```

The code could be optimized/improved a little bit, but it works for me. I omitted your WHERE and ORDER BY clauses to simplify my code, you just need to add them again. Let me know if it helps. Oh, and the MySQL DATEDIFF function returns the value in days by default, which I think is exactly what you want.

Comment: Diff(Days) - Need to remove brackets or enclose in single quote to avoid syntax error,

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @P.Salmon. Code corrected: Diff(Days) escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to assign row numbers and join

```
SELECT T.*, S.RN1,S.UPDATEDON,
         DATEDIFF(t.UPDATEDON,s.UPDATEDON) DIFF
FROM
(
SELECT T.*, 
         IF(T.MODULE <> @P , @RN:=1,@RN:=@RN+1) RN,
         @P:=T.MODULE P
FROM T
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @RN:=0,@P:='') R
where t.Module = 'LW2205'
order by t.module, t.id
)T 
LEFT JOIN
( 
SELECT T.*, 
         IF(T.MODULE <> @P1 , @RN1:=1,@RN1:=@RN1+1) RN1,
         @P1:=T.MODULE P1
FROM T
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @RN1:=0,@P1:='') R
where t.Module = 'LW2205'
order by t.module, t.id
) S
ON S.RN1 = T.RN - 1 AND S.MODULE = T.MODULE;
```

result

```
+------+--------+-------------------------+---------------------+------+--------+------+---------------------+------+
| ID   | Module | MoudleStatus            | UpdatedOn           | RN   | P      | RN1  | UPDATEDON           | DIFF |
+------+--------+-------------------------+---------------------+------+--------+------+---------------------+------+
|    4 | LW2205 | Draft exam received     | 2017-10-18 12:41:12 |    1 | LW2205 | NULL | NULL                | NULL |
|    5 | LW2205 | Draft exam received     | 2017-10-18 12:41:23 |    2 | LW2205 |    1 | 2017-10-18 12:41:12 |    0 |
|    7 | LW2205 | Draft exam received     | 2017-10-20 15:06:46 |    3 | LW2205 |    2 | 2017-10-18 12:41:23 |    2 |
|  275 | LW2205 | Exam approved by Dean   | 2017-11-14 16:39:28 |    4 | LW2205 |    3 | 2017-10-20 15:06:46 |   25 |
|  288 | LW2205 | Final exam sign off by  | 2017-11-21 12:28:59 |    5 | LW2205 |    4 | 2017-11-14 16:39:28 |    7 |
|  295 | LW2205 | Exam sent to SREO (Stud | 2017-11-23 09:53:30 |    6 | LW2205 |    5 | 2017-11-21 12:28:59 |    2 |
+------+--------+-------------------------+---------------------+------+--------+------+---------------------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note the result differs from your expected result

Comment: Thanks folks... Much appreciated... I was looking for a way to do this... I'll try it and revert back .... Thanks