# Subtracting two rows in the same column in mysq

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Hi i am having a table with the name Source. Here i have a data as shown below. Here i want to do subtraction between two rows. i.e. I want to do subtraction of 4th and 6th row and save the result in the new table with the name Dest and the with the same columns and the result row Name as M.

```
Dt          Week    Name    Total

2018/01     0         A      100

2017/12     48        A       2 

2018/01     0         B       61

2017/12     48        B        3

2018/01     0         C       61

2017/12    48         C        3 

2017/12    48         D       206

2017/12    48         E       1110

2017/12    48         F       1120

2017/12    48         G       113

2017/12    48         H       115

2017/12    48         I       111

2017/12    48         J       1140

2017/12    48         K       109

2017/12    48         L       1328
```

Please someone help me in achieving this.
Thanks

Comment: Yes at the end I want to generate a report using this data. So according to the report requirement I needa difference of this two rows

Comment: After subtracting these two values i have to do division for the result of subtractions with the all remaining rows.

Comment: as @scaisedge pointed out there is no way of identifying row 4 or row 6 from the data you have posted. This question is unclear and I'm voting to close.

Comment: Is this the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211142/timediff-between-rows (which is better expressed)

Comment: Yes, they both are some what similar @ P.Salmon

Comment: In that case I would keep an eye on it because I think it will attract workable answers.

Comment: It's hard to tell from your description what result you want. You might consider showing a sample of the result.   Please notice that SQL rows don't have any inherent numbering--the concept of _4th and 6th row_ makes no sense in SQL.